# php multi dimensional array grouping

Tags: php, arrays

Im a bit confuse on how to regroup a array based on a common value. Here is the array below:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
            [team] => 1
            [id] => 5
            [user] => teamleader1
            [Designation] => Team Leader
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [team] => 1
        [id] => 6
        [user] => consultant1
        [Designation] => Consultant
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [team] => 1
        [id] => 7
        [user] => consultant2
        [Designation] => Consultant
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [team] => 2
        [id] => 8
        [user] => consultant3
        [Designation] => Consultant
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [team] => 2
        [id] => 9
        [user] => teamleader2
        [Designation] => Team Leader
    )

)
```

and I would like to group it by its team value like the one below:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
    [0] => Array(
         [team] => 1
         [id] => 5
         [user] =>teamleader1
         [Designation] => Team Leader
     )
    [1] => Array(
         [team] => 1
         [id] => 6
         [user] =>consultant1
         [Designation] => Consultant
     )
    [2] => Array(
         [team] => 1
         [id] => 7
         [user] =>consultant2
         [Designation] => Consultant
     )
)
[2] => Array
    (
    [0] => Array(
         [team] => 1
         [id] => 8
         [user] =>consultant3
         [Designation] => Consultant
     )
    [1] => Array(
         [team] => 1
         [id] => 9
         [user] =>teamleader2
         [Designation] => Team Leader
     )
    )
)
```

The two main array groups are the teams itself. Any idea/help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$grouped = array();
foreach ($yourData as $item) {
  // copy item to grouped
  $grouped[$item['team']][] = $item;
}
var_dump($grouped);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/7ItbYDr4)

Comment: No need to check with isset, PHP creates it for you if it doesn't exists.

Comment: This screams Notice. But PHP5.3 actually doesn't raise one. Didn't know that… - still looks weird, though.

Comment: This does not give notices, see http://codepad.org/VdoMnfTD, PHP 5.2: http://ideone.com/vPTKw

Comment: thank you for your answers and help! with that small of code, it resolved my issue. Thanks a lot! Im using PHP 5.3.1 so I did not get any notices..